# Cooked Bay Tree

Tags: trees

I bought a small bay tree at lunchtime on a hot day and left it in my car until hometime. It got cooked with all the leaves pretty much dried out.

A friend told me I should take off most of the leaves so it could focus on feeding the remaining leaves. I did this.

I think what it was doing is growing the mini plants that were shooting out from the base because as soon as I stripped the leaves off the little plants started dying.

Now I basically just have two red shoots coming out of the soil at the base.

Have I completely killed the bay tree? Any advice please. Thanks.

EDIT: Added photos of the leaves and the little red shoot sprouting from the base.

[image: Bay tree with dried up leaves that have been mostly removed.]

[image: Shoots emerging from the roots]

EDIT2: As of this morning it really looks like the tree is pushing out those two red shoots at the expense of everything else. I guess I can try to grow two new trees from those.

[image: Red shoots growing up from the roots]

EDIT 3: A follow-on question would be... how do I separate the two red shoots from the main plant?

Comment: I think we really need a photo and please add some more information. How long ago did you buy and leave the tree in your car? Where has the plant been since you took it out of the car? Was the plant outdoors when you bought it, or under cover or indoors?

Comment: Good point, thank you. The tree was in the car without air conditioning for about 3.5 hours. Since then it has been indoors in a cool room with not that much sunlight but I'm keeping it well-watered. I'll edit the question and post photos later.